# Basic C++ programming question

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am in process of learning c++. I am working on creating a linkedlist data structure. One of the functions that displays the values of nodes in the structure does not work. For some reason the while loop that traverses through nodes doesn't work in the display function, hence I can't see the values in those nodes. Does anyone see what the problem is? I've been staring at the code for a while and not sure what is wrong here.
Thanks for your help in advance.
Header:

```
// linklist.h
// class definitions


#ifndef LINKLIST_H
#define LINKLIST_H

class linklist
 {
 private:
     // structure containing a data part and link part
     struct node
     {
         int data;
         node *link;
     }*p;

 public:

     linklist();
     void append(int num);
     void addatbeg(int num);
     void addafter(int loc, int num);
     void display();
     int count();
     void del(int num);
     ~linklist();
 };

#endif

.cpp file

// LinkedListLecture.cpp
// Class LinkedList implementation

    #include"linklist.h"
    #include<iostream>

using namespace std;


     // initializes data member
     linklist::linklist()
     {
         p =NULL;
     }

     // adds a node at the end of a linked list
     void linklist::append(int num)
     {
          node *temp, *r;
         // if the list is empty, create first node
         if(p==NULL)
         {
                 temp = new node;
             temp->data = num;
             temp->link = NULL;      
         }
         else
         {
             // go to last node
             temp = p;
             while(temp->link!=NULL)
                 temp =  temp->link;
             // add node at the end
             r = new node;
             r->data=num;
             r->link=NULL;
             temp->link=r;
         }
     }



 // displays the contents of the linked list
 void linklist::display()
 {
     node *temp = p;
     cout<< endl;
     // traverse the entire linked list
     while(temp!=NULL) // DEBUG: the loop doesn't work
     {
         cout<<temp->data<<" ";
         temp = temp->link;
     }

     void main() 
 {
     linklist l;

     l.append(14);
     l.append(30);
     l.append(25);
     l.append(42);
     l.append(17);
     cout<<"Elements in the linked list:";
     l.display(); // this function doesn't work
     system("PAUSE");
 }
```

Comment: In what way does it "not work"? What's the expected output, and what are you getting instead? (Also keep in mind that when you move to real production code that it'd be better to use the linked list that comes with the standard library, `std::list`)

Comment: [GWW's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165674/basic-c-programming-question/6165685#6165685) highlights that it's not `display()` that is causing you grief but `append()`. Once you've fixed that you may want to look at adding a `delete` for each `new`, to remove the [memory leaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never set p to a non NULL value.

```
    if(p==NULL)
     {
         p = new node;
         p->data = num;
         p->link = NULL;      
     }
```

Comment: Or better yet, move the node creation stuff to the top, and let the `if` and `else` just worry about hooking up the new node.

Answer (score 1):

I think GWW has highlighted the issue, but part of learning to program it to learn how to identify the mistakes.

If you do something and don't get the expected result you could:

- Use the visual c++ debugger to step through and see the values of your variables.
- Put in log lines to report information you think is important
- inspect the code - if you think something is right but it doesn't work, then go to an earlier step and check it does the right thing.
- Add unit tests, or follow design by contract adding pre/post conditions and class invariants.

Learning to program C++ by writing a linked list is like learning math by adding 1 + 1.  It is old fashioned thinking, slow and mostly boring without having any context.
Math isn't calculating, like C++ programming isn't pointer manipulation.  At some stage you might need to know about it, but your better off learning other important things like stl and boost.

If it was understood that `append()` ment create something, find the end of the list, add it.  you could then see that in you append function you have create something mixed uyp with move to the end of the list, but you never add it.

Comment: C++ programmers *should* do some simple projects with pointers, to understand how they work.  Using `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, and `std::vector` is a lot easier with any understanding of pointers.  That doesn't mean you need to be able to duplicate `unique_ptr` with all the intricacies, but without knowing some of the underlying allocation stuff, what you see in the debugger will be meaningless.

Comment: Unit testing would be a huge benefit here. A simple test like `linklist l; l.append(14); assert(l.p != NULL); assert(l.p->data == 14);` would identify the error quickly.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: don't disagree with you.